# Firebase iOS Push Notification in the background and foreground

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, push-notification

I would like to send a push notification to iOS device and achieve following behaviour:

If the app is in the foreground then trigger `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` as soon as notification arrives and also add notification to the notification tray.

If the app is in the background or app has been completely closed in the background then add notification to the notification tray.

At the moment, if I use `Data` payload I can get the notification to trigger `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` but only if the `Notification` payload is not set. As soon as I set `Notification` payload, notification goes into the tray and `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` is only triggered after user taps the notification and the app is opened.

Without the `Notification` payload the notification is not received (in either notification tray or by the app) when the app has been completely closed in the background.

I thought about sending two notification, one with `Notification` payload to make sure the notification tray displays the notification regardless of what state is the app in (even if it has been completely terminated) and one with `Data` payload as a `Background Notification` to update the data in the app when the app is in the foreground or running. Just feels wrong to send 2 notifications just to achieve something that feels as a fairly straight forward requirement.

Comment: use `willdisplay` notification delegate function

Comment: @Lu_ would you mind providing a bit more details? How would the FCM notification body look like to get the desired behaviour I have described? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To intercept notification when app is in foreground you should implement:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

and in function body call `completionHandler` with `.alert` to make it display normally

```
completionHandler(.alert)
```

That way you will not present anything and will have access to `notification.request.content.userInfo` inside this function